# Trouble getting started in wordpress - my experience isn't in wordpress.

Tags: customization

I know this topic is probably beat to death and I have beat almost all of my resources to death trying to figure this all out.

So I am a Ruby on Rails developer that's trying to create a wordpress site for my wife. She currently has a wordpress site but its completely out of date and she way overpaid for a purchased theme to be used and the monthly hosting fee is just crazy.

So I have a VPS with InMotionHosting and have wordpress installed. All the tutorials and videos I've found online just point to buying a theme and customizing it as far as you can with the "customizer" within wp-admin. I have searched for free themes but all these "free" themes are extremely limited on what you can customize within wp-admin to the point you have to buy the theme to get anywhere.

I know Ruby and the Ruby on Rails framework and I KNOW there's got to be more to building a decent wordpress website than just buying a theme and drag and dropping elements. I know PHP is used but once again I can open the themes with my code editor but not sure if this is how I need to be able to customize it.

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try my theme, it's based on Bootstrap, if you understand how bootstrap themes are built then you can easily modify my theme -- https://github.com/kadimi/bootswatch (demo: http://kadimi.com)

Comment: Thanks for the link! I do know how bootstrap works as I've used it in the past within rails apps.

Comment: I added and example in the `README.md` file just for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try one of the better books on how WordPress works and the easiest ways to customize it.

I recommend the book on DigWP - https://digwp.com/book/

Also, this site is a great help for people getting started - http://www.wpbeginner.com/